# Running three functions at once?

Tags: c++, function

C++
Working on a problem for school, running 3 horses in a race and whoever finishes first is the winner. the 3 horses are supposed to run in sync like this

```
1|--------H------|
2|-------H-------|
3|---------H-----|
```

However my code runs the program correctly (generate a random number between 1 and 100 and if that number is less than 50 move the horse 1 space up). but it runs the first horse, then the 2nd and the 3rd last.

tried to look this up but none of the methods seem to work (using codeblocks (latest version Windows 10) for C++).

```
srand(time(NULL));
Horse1();
Horse2();
Horse3();
```

Github file:  https://gist.github.com/EthanA2020/f16a699f1b8136a1da0350ab48acdda0

Answer (score 2):

I don't think your issue is with the type of function but instead the structure of your program. No matter how you program, one operation must come before the next. Developers work with this by running each operation of the object (in your case the horse movement) side by side and checking later to see the outcome.

For example, lets use your horse scenario:

```
while "all horses" are less than "finish"
     horse 1 moves
     horse 2 moves
     horse 3 moves
```

I am sure that you are familiar with loops so we'll use that here. Some set distance must exist to determine when a horse has finished. So you'll want to continue that loop while all horses have a distance less than that value. During each loop, each horse's movement value must either change or not (determined by your random movement function).

Now once this while loop has ended, you can be sure that at least one horse has crossed the finish line. All operations have been completed and you have a data set of the horses positions. This is the point where you check to see which horses have finished (I say horses plural because there is a chance that more than one horse or even all 3 finish at the same time, so be sure to factor that in at the end).

With that, your program structure should be something like:

```
while "all horses" are less than "finish"
     horse 1 moves
     horse 2 moves
     horse 3 moves
//movement of horses complete
check and print the horses with a movement value of "finish"
```

Comment: What i did was time the amount of time it took for the program to run then wrote a function to calculate who had the best time.

Comment: That works just as well, good job! Just keep in mind that if you created individual functions for each horse, that could be optimized by putting the core program in a loop and running each horse through it rather than typing the same code three times.

Answer (score -4):

I think you should do:

```
while (!horse(rand() % 100)) {
    usleep(100);
}
```

Where `horse(int n)` moves horse `n` 1 position and if it reached the end, it returns `true` (to end the race). It does nothing if an invalid `n` (only 1 to 3 is valid) is passed to it.